# What happens to old links if i change link domain with the route configurations in branch.io

Tags: javascript, frontend, branch.io

I have a branch.io app with example.app.link as domain and bunch of links got created where
it opens "**ExampleApp**" in appstore or playstore.

Now due to some reason i need to change the domain(newexample.app.link or new.example.com) of the link(either sub domain or a new domain completly if subdomain doesn't work) along with the redirection configurations.
So my new redirection is "**ExampleAppNew**"

Will the previously created links will open the old app or new app or error page?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for reaching out to Branch Support. If you change the domain the old links will stop working, but if you use subdomain it should not cause any issues. We are attaching documentation for your reference.

https://help.branch.io/using-branch/docs/advanced-settings-configuration#domain-change-warning

Comment: I have gone through this before. But this says the opposite.

example.app.link --- newExample.app.link -- Doc says older link will not work
example.app.link --- newExample.example.com --  Doc says oledr link will also work.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).